# PHP/mySQL count total comments per country code

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have three tables in mySQL - category, topics, and comments. I'm trying to count the total comments to a topic and group each country code by the total count. At the moment there is several country codes that appear multiple times in comments_location in the comments table which contains the different country codes (e.g. US,UK,CH,ETC). However, these country codes can appear multiple times in comments_location. I'd like to group the comments_location (e.g. the comments_location has 3 UK records, 2 US records, etc - rather than appearing three times, I'd like to group the comments_location (by a single UK,US,ETC) and show the total number of records for each country). Below is an example of an attempt but it's not working:

```
// should there be a FOR statement and where should it be placed?
//query comments where comment location = (US,UK,ETC.)
$sqlcomment = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE comments_location='NEED TO RUN THROUGH EACH COUNTRY CODE AND GROUP e.g. (GROUP US - run count, then GROUP UK - run count, ETC)'");
//get comment total (run count)
$commentnumber = mysql_num_rows($sqlcomment);
//echo each variable into a string one by one (should the FOR be placed here?)
$variable1 = "CODE: NEED VARIABLE FOR COMMENTS_LOCATION, value: $commentnumber, ";
echo $variable1;
```

Ideally, the echo $variable1 should show CODE: US, value: 2240, CODE: UK, value: 6240, CODE: CH, value: 3240, etc continue looping until all the possible country codes have been listed.

Do I need to store an array of all the possible country codes and place them WHERE comments_location is in $sqlcomment?

Comment: No way to do this nicely. Since your comments_location essentially contains a CSV file, you can't use native database grouping, because it knows NOTHING of your fields inner structure. Your table needs to be normalized before you can use a plain `group by` statement.

Comment: ... Are you sure that the comments_location contains multiple entries not just a single one? I understood it that way, that each column = e.g. comments_location="uk".

Comment: I was thinking to list all of the country codes into a seperate table and linking that to comments_location, but the issue will still be there as there will be multiple country codes in the comments table

Comment: You have per comment a single country code or multiple?

Comment: @D. Schalla there are multiple comments, and each comment has a comments_location based on what the user enters from a dropdown list on a form (e.g. UK,US,CH,Etc). As an example, I would like to group all of the UK entries in the comments table, count them and then echo each country code group out one by one along with the total count for that country code group

Comment: Please edit your question to provide sample data and desired results to better describe what you want to do.

Comment: I wrote a SQL function a while back that parses a field with CSV and then uses the results to work with in a CASE statement. Have a look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615729/maximum-of-case-statements-in-query EDIT: it occurs to me that you're not explaining your issue well. Please provide a sample of the table layout and data contained in each. I believe that @D.Schalla's answer will be correct.

Comment: @user3133586: I think you can savely use my answer then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the following query:

```
$sqlcomment = mysql_query("SELECT comments_location,count(comments_id)as count FROM comments GROUP BY comments_location");
echo'<pre>';
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sqlcomment)){
   print_r($row);
}
echo'</pre>';
```

comments_id was a guess, adapt that when required.

This should give you **n** results, while n=Count of the Countries. You will have per row then the Country + the Count.

Comment: I was just about to submit my answer which is exactly the same when this showed up

Comment: Glad to hear this! But it seems there is some confusion about the absolut database layout, see comments at main question

Comment: This outputs an array for each group but the count isn't working - [comments_location] => UK
    [1] => 11
    [count] => 11
)
there are only 2 records of the UK, yet it is showing 11

Comment: It's taking the comments_id and adding the values - comments_id is a primary key and set to auto increment, I would like to count the total records by group

Comment: Yes indeed. I had a bug in the first code where I took sum() instead of count(); glad it is working now! :)